# What is this new insignia in Iraq?

Tags: iraq

Iraq's government seems to be rapidly evolving, developing new armies to cope with ISIL, and making various political changes. I recently saw this new insignia being worn by a member of the Iraqi armed forces. What is it?

[image]

Comment: Never seen that one. Are you sure he's part of the Iraqi army?

Comment: Any other details? Source for the image, location, etc.

Comment: @Geobits This is photo from the current battle happening at Mosul where the Iraqi army is fighting DAESH/ISIL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the logo of the [Iraqi Counter Terrorism Bureau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iraqi_Special_Operations_Forces#/media/File:Flag_of_the_Iraqi_Counter_Terrorism_Bureau.svg) (ICTB), although the coloring is slightly different.